# Remote Access To Excel-database - Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, remote-access, vba

In my company we have all products in an Excel-database. When a customer (shops) wants to place an order, they fax a form with item No etc. The order is entered through a VBA form, returning info about "in stock" etc, and the order is subtracted from the stock and placed in worksheet.

Now I would like to know, if its possible - without too much fuss, to do this from the www, so a customer can access the database and see if the item is in stock (which is not the hard part) - AND place the order so the database is updated in our local workbook.

I'm not asking for actual code, but ideas to a general approach.

Is it possible to run VBA forms from a remote computer?

Will XML, ASP etc be the answer?

Other ideas?

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you using an Excel-database for this? Why not SQL or Access? With an SQL db you could remotely connect to it using Excel and a bit of VBA fairly easily.

Comment: Excel should not really be used as a database.  For an Office product, use Access.  For what you are looking for, I think you need to use SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This is all fairly easy to do if you have a **proper** database, there are all kinds of reasons not to use Excel.

Your best approach would likely be to build a web system around a database and move all application logic there.

But in your specific case it might be easier to build it around Sharepoint.

Comment: Why Sharepoint? Sounds like possibly a very expensive option. Depending on the scale of the business surely it would be better to opt for a SQL/MySQL option and build it into the existing interface?

Comment: I'm basing that statement on the idea that their current workflow is centered around Excel, recreating that as a Sharepoint workflow *could* be easy (even if expensive).